Compile an XSD schema with JAXB in Eclipse 2024 and JDK 22
I want to work with Eclipse and jdk 22 with JAXB to compile an xsd schema in order to generate the java classes.
I don't have a Maven installation except the one built into Eclipse itself.
To do this I create a maven project in Eclipse and configure pom.xml as follows:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prueba</groupId>
    <artifactId>ruebaJAXB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaFiles>
                        <schemaFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/personas.xsd</schemaFile>
                    </schemaFiles>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src/capaNegocio</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I have a schema in src/main/resources. If I right-click on it under the Generate option, I only see the XML File option.
What steps do I need to take to generate Java classes from this schema?

Which version of JAXB API are you targeting ? Jakarta-based 4.x or Javax-based 2.3 ? You're importing API 4.x but Runtime 2.3 which are incompatible... In order to launch generation from Eclipse, you could right-click on the project itself and then "run as" menu -> "maven generate sources"

After you right-click on the project and let it Maven -> Update Project..., right-click on it again, choosing Run As... -> Maven Build... and make sure xjc is in the Goals text field.

If you are using a recent Eclipse version, this should integrate the auto building process for maven projects with the jaxb2-maven-plugin without too much effort from the user (at least, a confirm that it has to install an addition for maven lifecycle mapping to manage that maven plugin).
You don't have usually to use the Generate > JAXB Classes... menu because the integration of the plugin in the building pipeline should already have generated all the xsd described classes automatically.
As an alternative to the jaxb2-maven-plugin, you can also consider using the cxf-xjc-plugin by Apache, like this:
<properties>
  <org.apache.cxf.xjc.version>4.0.2</org.apache.cxf.xjc.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>${org.apache.cxf.xjc.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${org.apache.cxf.xjc.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>xjc</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <configuration>
            <fork>always</fork>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <additionalJvmArgs>-Duser.language=en</additionalJvmArgs>
            <xsdOptions>
              <xsdOption>
                <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/personas.xsd</xsd>
                <packagename>com.mypackage</packagename>
              </xsdOption>
            </xsdOptions>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

In this case, the generated sources are put under the target/generated/src/main/java/com/mypackage directory.
Also in this case, the integration in Eclipse is quite seamlessy and the plugin appears in the Lifecycle Mapping of the project; the sources are generated automatically during the project building phase.
